# node.js - extract XML fragments from large XML files

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js

I work on a node.js application for processing and loading large amounts of geospatial data from files into a JSON document database.

The source data is in the form of large (up to 10's of GB) XML documents. I used [sax.js](https://github.com/isaacs/sax-js) to parse the source documents, which gives me JavaScript objects representative of the XML structure:

```
{ name: 'gml:featureMember',
  attributes: {},
  isSelfClosing: false,
  parent: null,
  children: 
   [ '\r\n        ',
     { name: 'AX_BesondereFlurstuecksgrenze',
       attributes: { 'gml:id': 'DEHHALKAn0007s8z' },
       isSelfClosing: false,
       children: 
        [ '\r\n          ',
          { name: 'gml:identifier',
            attributes: { codeSpace: 'http://...' },
            isSelfClosing: false,
            children: [ 'urn:adv:oid:...' ] },
          '\r\n          ',
          { name: 'lebenszeitintervall',
            attributes: {},
            isSelfClosing: false,
            children: 
             [ '\r\n            ',
               { name: 'AA_Lebenszeitintervall',
                 attributes: {},
                 isSelfClosing: false,
                 children: 
                  [ '\r\n              ',
                    { name: 'beginnt',
                      attributes: {},
                      isSelfClosing: false,
                      children: [ '2010-03-07T08:32:05Z' ] },
                    '\r\n            ' ] },
               '\r\n          ' ] },
          ...
```

However, sax.js apparently gives no access to the current fragment. So I am looking for a way to get an XML Fragment from sax.js or a different stream parser. As I am on Windows, I would like to use only modules that don't require compilation.

Comment: You can try using XPath/Xquery.

Comment: Is there an xpath/yquery implementation that is based just on sax.js and doesn't require compilation? I briefly looked at saxtract and other, but they all seem to use libxmljs.

Comment: To get only the XML fragment, you can directly use XPath in javascript. Nice introduction is given here: https://timkadlec.com/2008/02/xpath-in-javascript-introduction/

Comment: @Jagrut I saw that there is a pure javascript implementation of Xpath for node.js as well https://www.npmjs.com/package/xpath.js(), but it requires a DOM parser. I don't think I can use a DOM parser for XML files with several Gigabytes.

Comment: Alright, I followed the Xpath path and was able to solve the issue using https://www.npmjs.com/package/saxpath. Memory usage stayed below 70MB in node while processing a 1.7GB file, though there were some longer (garbage collection?) delays during processing.

Comment: Can you show the code so that I can take a look and give better suggestions?

Comment: Thanks Jagrut, I added an answer based on your tip. If you see something that can be improved, we can have the discussion there.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a suggestion by @Jagrut, I searched for an XPath implementation for node.js that works with sax.js and doesn't require a DOM or a native library. I found [saxpath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/saxpath) that fits the bill.

Usage is as follows:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var saxParser = require('sax').createStream(true);
var saxPath = require('saxpath');

var dataURL = '../data/ALKIS_FHH_0167.xml';
var count = 0;

parseXML(dataURL);

function parseXML(fileName) {

    var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(fileName);
    var streamer = new saxPath.SaXPath(saxParser, '//gml:featureMember');

    streamer.on('match', function(xml) {
        addFeature(xml);
    });

    fileStream.pipe(saxParser);
}

function addFeature (featureFragment) {
    // for now we just count features...
    if (count % 100 == 0) {
        console.log("Parsing fragment " + count);
    }
    count++;
}
```

It has a much nicer API than directly using sax.js. The only caveat I have noticed is that parsing sometimes stops for several seconds, probably due to GC. I tested this with XML files up to 1.7GB.

Comment: I am not much aware of saxpath, but can you, instead of loading the entire XML in first place, directly apply XPath on the document and then parse it? I am not sure, but just a thought!